# SQL: Convert Date to Null when Date is certian range from Today

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am working with an Oracle Datebase and I want to convert a date to null when it is more than a certain number of months from today.
The date format I am using is `dd-mm-yy`
So lets say you have this table:

```
WITH TEST_TABLE as (select '1' as num, '10-FEB-16' from dual
union(select '2', '10-FEB-30' from dual)
union(select '3', '10-FEB-50' from dual)
union(select '4', '10-FEB-17' from dual))
```

I know I can use: `SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;` to get todays date but I am not sure how to compare this by months.

How would I change the dates to null when they are greater than say 24 months from today?

Comment: [`ADD_MONTHS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions004.htm) is likely to be your friend here.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment @matt-gibson. Something like `ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 12 * 2)` would compare 24 months, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
update test_table
    set dte = (case when add_months(dte, -12) < sysdate then dte end);
```

Note:  You should be storing a date as a `date` data type in the database.  The output format (by default) is the DD-MMM-YY format.  But that is just the date formatted for output.

Comment: If this is to be done on a table with many rows, it is better to apply add_months to sysdate, rather than to dte; then the calculation is done only once (assuming the Oracle optimizer is smart enough to detect that... is it?)